# GWT - Reference to a global variable set by callback method

Tags: gwt, variables, methods, callback, scope

Please help me, as I will go mad with this soon:

When I run the code, on first occasion loadNewPoint() is executed and displays some data from global variable - allPointsAndPlaces

However when I click a button (from a child class), the same method loadNewPoint() gives me null pointer for allPointsAndPlaces.

I have changed the code structure a lot from an original trying to solve this issue, and moved this method (loadNewPoint()) to a parent class to see, if it would solve the issue.

Parent class:

```
public class CabbieApp implements EntryPoint {

  private GetLocationsServiceAsync getAllLocationsService = GWT.create(GetLocationsService.class);
  CabbiePoint[] allPointsAndPlaces;
  PointsQuiz quiz;

  /**
   * Entry point method.
   */
  public void onModuleLoad() {

      //Get all the required data from DB
      getAllPointsAndLocations();

  }

  private void loadAppPages(){
      // Associate the Main panel with the HTML host page.
      RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("pointsList");    

      quiz = new PointsQuiz();

      rootPanel.setStyleName("GWTapp");
      rootPanel.add(quiz.getMainPanel());

      loadNewPoint();

  }


    private void getAllPointsAndLocations() {
        // Initialize the service proxy.
        if (getAllLocationsService == null) {
            getAllLocationsService = GWT.create(GetLocationsService.class);
        }

        // Set up the callback object.
        AsyncCallback<CabbiePoint[]> callback = new AsyncCallback<CabbiePoint[]>() {
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
              System.out.println(caught.getMessage());
          }

          public void onSuccess(CabbiePoint[] result) {
            //allPointsAndPlaces = result;
            System.out.println(result.length);
            allPointsAndPlaces = result;
            loadAppPages();


          }
        };

        // Make the call to the service.
        getAllLocationsService.getLocations(callback);

    }


    void loadNewPoint(){
        int r = Random.nextInt(allPointsAndPlaces.length);
        quiz.CurrentPlace = allPointsAndPlaces[r].getPlaceName();
        quiz.CurrentLocation = allPointsAndPlaces[r].getPlaceLocation();

        quiz.point.setText(quiz.CurrentPlace);
        quiz.location.setText(quiz.CurrentLocation);
        quiz.location.setStyleName("invisibleText");
    }

  }
```

Child class:

```
public class PointsQuiz extends CabbieApp{

       VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
       HorizontalPanel navigation = new HorizontalPanel();
       TextBox point = new TextBox();
       TextBox location = new TextBox();
       Button showLocation = new Button("Show Location");
       Button nextPoint = new Button("Next Point");
       String CurrentPlace, CurrentLocation;


      public PointsQuiz() {

          // Assemble Add Stock panel.
              navigation.add(showLocation);
              navigation.add(nextPoint);
              navigation.setCellHorizontalAlignment(nextPoint, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
              navigation.addStyleName("addPanel");
              mainPanel.setSpacing(5);
              mainPanel.setStyleName("body");
              mainPanel.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
              mainPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

            // Assemble Main panel.
            mainPanel.add(point);
            point.setWidth("200px");
            mainPanel.add(location);
            location.setWidth("200px");
            mainPanel.add(navigation);
            navigation.setWidth("200px");

         // Move cursor focus to the input box.
            showLocation.setFocus(true);

         // Listen for mouse events on the show location button.
            showLocation.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                showCurrentLocation();}
              });


             // Listen for mouse events on the next point button.
            nextPoint.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                loadNewPoint();
                  }
            });       
      }



        private void showCurrentLocation(){
            location.setStyleName("visibleText");
        }

        public VerticalPanel getMainPanel() {
            return mainPanel;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null pointer error because of `allPointsAndPlaces` is null. As per your coding The value of  `allPointsAndPlaces` is assigned after completion of RPC call in getAllPointsAndLocations() method.  so the `allPointsAndPlaces` has some assigned values.

Here you try to directly access `loadNewPoint()` method in child class. At a time, `allPointsAndPlaces` is not assigned.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I do understand the problem.

Comment: However on the occasion, when I try to run loadNewPoint() from a child class by clicking a button, the RPC has finished, and the loadNewPoint() was already run once. How is this possible, that when a method was invoked once already and has used allPointsAndPlaces absolutely fine, it doesn't see the same reference again? And how can I change the code to avoid that and make allPointsAndPlaces accesible by other methods?

Comment: `allPointsAndPlaces` is object so its default value is null. while you create a instance of PointsQuiz so indirectly CabbieApp as super class its created. and allPointsAndPlaces will assigned null.if you want to manage `allPointsAndPlaces` status so you have to make as a static object. so do `static CabbiePoint[] allPointsAndPlaces;` your problem will solved.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution to this problem with Bhumika's help.

To make this work I had to change `CabbiePoint[] allPointsAndPlaces` to static.

This would solve the reference problem one way - from child to parent.

Also I managed to find out trough debugging, that this reference

```
quiz = new PointsQuiz();
```

is also null on a second run of `loadNewPoint()`. So this child reference (`PointsQuiz quiz;`) and any other references to children were set also to static.